# Is it possible in C# to write an implicit conversion operator for both nullable and non-nullable values?

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion, non-nullable

I am trying to write an `Alias` class which enables me to:

```
int n = new Count(1);
```

That is, it encapsulates an `int` in this case as a `Count`, which gives some type safety and domain meaning, while it automatically converts back to the underlying type.

With non-nullable reference types, I have another issue. I cannot figure out how to handle both of these scenarios at the same time:

```
int someCount = new Count(1);
Count? nothing = null;
int? noCount = nothing;
```

This happens because I have types like this:

```
record Device(Count Cpu, Count? Cores); // Contrived example
```

Seems like the problem is I cannot overload an operator with both nullable and non-nullable version of the same type:

```
record Alias<T>(T Value)
{
  public static implicit operator T(Alias a) => a.Value;
  public static implicit operator T?(Alias? a) => null;
}

record Count : Alias<int> { /**/ }
```

The point is, if I have a null, I want it converted to null of the target type.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to flag T as not nullable, or is nullable T a requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. If I understand nullable reference types, it is mostly annotations etc to help the compiler warn about problems, not an actual different type. So your two operators could have the same signature. It might work better if you restricted T to a struct, or used a custom maybe/option type.

Comment: @Eterm, see my `Device` example. Nullable T is a requirement.

Comment: @JonasH, I was hoping to avoid `Maybe` and siblings, and use native C# all the way.

Comment: In my experience, nullable reference types just do not play well with generics, so you probably have to pick your poison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using `NotNullIfNotNullAttribute`. Here's an example where `SpecialString` needs to be cast-able to `string` (and vice-versa) and needs to support both null and not-null instances:

```
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(SpecialString))]
public static implicit operator string?(SpecialString? SpecialString) =>
    SpecialString is null ? null : SpecialString.Value;

[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(value))]
public static implicit operator SpecialString?(string? value) => 
    value is null ? null : new(value);
```

For more information, see the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) article.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any `Alias`es that wraps reference types, then I think the best thing to do here is to just limit `T` here to `struct`s. After that, `T`, and `T?` become distinct types, allowing you to create two operators:

```
record Alias<T>(T Value) where T: struct
{
    public static implicit operator T?(Alias2<T>? a) => a?.Value;
    public static implicit operator T(Alias2<T> a) => a.Value;
}
```

If you also need to wrap reference types as well, you could consider adding another `Alias` type that works just for reference types:

```
record AliasClass<T>(T Value) where T: class
{
  [return: NotNullIfNotNull("a")]
  public static implicit operator T?(AliasClass<T>? a) => a?.Value;
}

record AliasStruct<T>(T Value) where T: struct
{
    
  public static implicit operator T?(AliasStruct<T>? a) => a?.Value;
  public static implicit operator T(AliasStruct<T> a) => a.Value;
}
```

Then you can have for example:

```
record Count(int Value) : AliasStruct<int>(Value) { /**/ }
record StringWrapper(string Value) : AliasClass<string>(Value) { /**/ }
```

Comment: Then I have to select my `Alias` based on the underlying type, which I want to avoid. Those are implementation details.

Comment: @ThomasEyde I don't think the value type/reference type distinction is an "implementation detail"... It is very much grounded in the nature of the C# language and the CLR itself. I guess we'll just agree to disagree...

Comment: From my point of view, when designing this, it is an implementation detail. Unfortunately, the current state of C# denies me that.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, it's not possible to overload an operator with both nullable and non-nullable generic types.

I kind of solved it with extension methods:

```
public static class AliasClass
{
    public static V? Unwrap<V, A>(this Alias<V, A>? a)
        where A : Alias<V, A> where V : class => a?.Value;
}

public static class AliasStruct
{
    public static V? Unwrap<V, A>(this Alias<V, A>? a)
        where A : Alias<V, A> where V : struct => a?.Value;
}

[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "VirtualMemberCallInConstructor")]
public abstract record Alias<V, A> where A : Alias<V, A>
{
    protected Alias(V value)
    {
        Value = value;
        EnsureValid(Value);
    }

    public V Value { get; }
    protected virtual void EnsureValid(V value) { }
    public override sealed string ToString() => Value?.ToString() ?? "";
    public static implicit operator V(Alias<V, A> a) => a.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
int a = new Count(1);
int? n = new Count(2).Unwrap();
```

The symmetry, sadly, is broken. I can't find a way to implement `Unwrap()` for the non-nullable case.