# Convert a c# variable to its Nullable form using null

Tags: c#, types, nullable

I'm trying to return a value of type `A?` from a method `Value`. The method returns `null` conditionally as I'm trying to shield the caller from obtaining a value `A` in some cases (without throwing exceptions):

```cs
public class Container<A>
{
    private readonly A? _value;
    public readonly bool ShouldBeNull;
    public A? Value => ShouldBeNull ? null : _value;

    public Container(A value, bool shouldBeNull)
    {
        ShouldBeNull = shouldBeNull;
        _value = shouldBeNull ? default(A) : value;
    }
}
```

I would expect the code to compile: the return type is explicitly marked as nullable (`A?`) meaning the caller can expect the return type to be null. The code does not compile however with error:

> Cannot convert null to type parameter 'A' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(A)' instead.

If I constrain type `A` to be a value type (`where A : struct`), the code compiles. But what I don't understand, is that if I constrain type `A` to be a reference type (`where A : class`) the code compiles as well.

If this is the case, why does above code snippet not work with no constraints? Is there any way to make the snippet compile with `A` being either a value or a reference type?

This question was answered in a different form here: [How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c). However, I would like to find *why* the snippet doesn't work. If the compiler can make the snippet work in case of a value or reference type, why can't it work for both?

Comment: Because `A?` means different things to the runtime depending on whether `A` is a value type or reference type. When `A` is a value type, `A?` means `Nullable<A>`. When `A` is a reference type, `A?` just means `A`, because the runtime doesn't really know very much about nullable reference types at all.

Comment: NRTs in generally don't work well with generics - you'd often have to make two versions of the same thing, one for value types and one for reference types. also [this explanation I wrote some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594285/5133585), or [this recent question that is very similar to your situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73620707/5133585).